# fprintf() on a new line of a file

Tags: c

How i can make a new line at the end of a file to fprintf() user inputed text?
My code right now is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int lines;
    int number;
    FILE *fp;
    printf("Insert random number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    fp = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        if (ch=='\n') {
            lines++;
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fopen("textfile.txt", "ab");
    fseek(fp, lines, SEEK_SET);
    fprintf(fp,"%d", number);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `'\n'` to the `fprintf()` like this

```
fprintf(fp,"\n%d", number)
/*           ^  */
```

but you also need a lot of error checking, for instance `fopen()` returns `NULL` when it fails to open the file.

Your code is actually very broken, you count the lines in the file opened with `"r"`, i.e. for reading, then you call `fopen()` with `"ab"` but discard the return value, you then `fseek()` the number of lines, and `fseek()` is for the number of characters not lines, then you write to the closed `fp` pointer, because

```
fopen("textfile.txt", "ab"); /* you don't assign the return value anywhere */
fseek(fp, lines, SEEK_SET);  /* this is the same pointer you `fclosed()'   */
/*         ^ this will not seek to the end of the file                     */
fprintf(fp,"%d", number);    /* here `fp' is still invalid                 */
```

Test this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE       *file;
    const char *filename = "textfile.txt";


    printf("Insert a number: ");    
    if (scanf("%d", &number) != 1)
     {
        fpritnf(stderr, "invalid input, expected a number\n");
        return -1;
     }
    file = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (file == NULL)
     {
        fprintf(stderr, "cannot open %s for appending\n", filename);
        return -1;
     }
    fprintf(file, "\n%d", number);
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

You don't need to `fseek()` if you open with `"a"` because new content is appended to the end of the file, you need a `'\n'` before the user input if there was no `'\n'` in the file or if you want to force the new value in a new line.

You don't need the `"b"` in the mode string, because you are writing text to the file, and on some platforms the file will have issues when you open it in a text editor.

Comment: It makes a new line after fprintf(), but i need to put user input on the new line in the end of file.

Comment: Well try `fprintf(fp,"\n%d", number)`

Comment: @Carel155 you just need to read the documentation, for example your `fseek()` is very simple like this `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);`. Instead of the complicated code that you wrote.

Comment: It is adding user input to the end of the last line in the .txt document. But i need to put user input on the newline at the end.

Comment: @Carel155 as @RiggsFolly commented, just move the `'\n'`.

Comment: Its making space, not a new line

Comment: @Carel155 you had a very sever error in your code, I fixed it.